# C# Get "real" icon for temporary file

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, icons

I noticed that when I run some installers that create a tmp file, windows is still able to get the correct icon even though the tmp file has a blank icon.

I simply have a backgroundworker with a while loop that watches for new processes and displays there icons in a form. I am using the `SHGetFileInfo` ways to get icons from the filename provided with the process, but I don't know how to extract the "real" icon from a given tmp file name like `C:\...\is-0N5SF.tmp\setup.tmp`.

Is there some way I could get the process that created/launched the tmp file or a way that I could resolve the path to the real file/icon?

Answer (score 1):

Temporary files don't *necessarily* have icons because they're ephemeral, and their content is defined by the host application. A .tmp file might contain XML data, a Zip archive, an executable or one of a lot of other things. Getting a temporary file's icon isn't the right way to get the process' icon.

Get the process' window, use [`GetClassInfoEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633579.aspx) to get the window class data, and make a copy of the `hIcon` member. (Not the handle, the data.)